# How to add content to dynamically created tab with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I attach content to dynamically created tab?
if I leave a div with that id there is a mess.

1. the third tab content apper in the first tab
2. after I click the checkbox it looks good but in the third click
   (hide and show again) the third tab content dissaper.

How can I press the checkbox to show and hide the tab and and his content dynamically?

live: http://jsfiddle.net/dSxby/

html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <label for="dp_add_license">Add tab</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="dp_add_license" name="dp_add_license" value="1"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>tab  2 content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>tab 3 content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
      $('#dp_add_license').click(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $("#tabs").tabs("add", '#tabs-3', "tab 3");
          } else {
              $("#tabs").tabs("remove", '#tabs-3');
          }
      });
});
```

Comment: You can use jquery .append function to dynamically add tab.

Answer (score 2):

Style the `id="tabs-3"` to `display:none;`: http://jsfiddle.net/dSxby/1/

```
<div id="tabs-3" style='display:none;'>
    <p>tab 3 content.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: faster answer...just writing it.

Comment: thanks but it doesn;t work with a few more clicks on the checkbox as i sad before tab 3 content dissaper